# Adding processing instruction to xml before root element with cElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xslt, celementtree

I am using `cElementTree` library to produce xml files. Now I want to write `.xsl` file for better readability. That's why I need to add `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>` before first tag. Unfortunately I was able to put desired line only after first tag:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as Et
test_report = Et.Element("TEST_REPORT")
root = test_report
root.append(Et.ProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"'))
...
...
tree = Et.ElementTree(root)
tree.write(self.file_name+"_result.xml")
```

Witch logically produces:

```
<TEST_REPORT>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
...
...
</TEST_REPORT>
```

What I need is:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<TEST_REPORT>
...
...
</TEST_REPORT>
```

I am looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8200120/3240679) but it seems like there is no `addprevious` method in cElementTree.

Comment: If all you want to do is **write** xml (not parse it), have a look at the http://www.yattag.org library. It's easy to do what you want using the `asis` method.

Comment: Unfortunately I will have to parse it later to put results to HP Quality Center. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868248/how-to-create-doctype-with-pythons-celementtree